# Can MapReduce be used to efficiently sum up integers from a huge file?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, sum

[The file is too big to read into RAM.]

Here is my formulation:

- The mapper would take each integer `x` and emit `('anything', x)`.
- During the sort phase, all the key-value pairs will be grouped by key: `('anything', [x1, x2, x3, ...])`.
- The reducer would add up all the integers for each key and emit the sum.

But since I have the same key for all the key-value pairs, wouldn't it be very inefficient because there would be 1 reducer adding up all the integers?

What is the correct way to solve this problem using MapReduce?

Comment: Couldn't you use, say, 100 keys to sum everything in 100 buckets and then just sum the 100 numbers together?

Comment: ideally you would just emit the sum per map task, even on a large file this is on the order of 10k-100k, that's not that bad to group on a single key. Also why would you need to read the whole file into RAM to compute a sum?

Comment: If the file is already sharded, sure, but if not, it'd be simpler to do it all locally: just read one number at a time and keep a running total; you pretty much can't get faster than that, and you don't need the whole thing in RAM at once, just one number from the file at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count this on a single machine you would not need to have the file entirely in RAM at once, but if the file was huge enough that it would take too long to stream it through a single machine then you would find a big optimization to your MapReduce algorithm by using a combiner that was identical to your reducer.

A combiner acts as a reducer, but run for each mapper before the results are sent to the reducers. In this case your single reducer would receive only one record per mapper - the sum for that mapper. With a mapper typically processing 128MB of data (the size of each HDFS block of a huge file), you would need an incredibly large file for a typical single reducer to be burdened.

More information on combiners can be found on the [Apache Hadoop](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopMapReduce) website.